# Vmware workstation won't open, get message box "Could not initialize logging"

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I use VMWare workstation on my Windows 7 development machine. The VMs host various versions of SQL server and operating systems for testing. I last used a VM a few days ago. When I tried to open VMWare yesterday I got a message box stating  "Could not initialize logging" VMWare does not open so I cant look at properties, settings, etc. Any thoughts on how to repair?

In the log file hostd-1820.log I find the following entry: "2019-01-14T08:55:07.836-08:00 [02776 error 'Default'] An error occurred while loading configuration "C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\ft-vmx-version.ini",not all entries are being read. It is strongly encouraged that you manually inspect the file and fix any corruptions." I looked in this directory but can not find the file. Is there a way to recreate it?